# Gram Schmidt algorithm using nympy/sympy for a custom inner product space

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a Gram Schmidt algorithm using numpy or sympy for a special inner product space (so not the euclidean one). The inner product space is

[image]

And the vectors are

[image]

```py
def inner_product(x, y):
    return x[0]*y[0] + 2*x[1]*y[1] + x[2]*y[2]

def gram_schmidt(V):
 U = []
 for i in range(len(V)):
   # start with the current vector
   u = V[i]
   for j in range(i):
     # subtract the projection of V[i] onto each U[j]
     proj = (inner_product(V[i], U[j]) / inner_product(U[j], U[j])) * U[j]
     u = u - proj
   # normalize
   U.append(u / np.linalg.norm(u))
 return np.array(U)

V = np.array([[1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2]])
U = gram_schmidt(V)
print(U)
```

It could be great if the algorithm could print all the steps for the proces

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem are you facing? Your question involves three vectors, while your definition only mentions two. Is this operation associative?  Why can't you simply multiply the second value of each vector by two?

Comment: import numpy as np

def inner_product(x, y):
    return x[0]*y[0] + 2*x[1]*y[1] + x[2]*y[2]

def gram_schmidt(V):
    U = []
    for i in range(len(V)):
        # start with the current vector
        u = V[i]
        for j in range(i):
            # subtract the projection of V[i] onto each U[j]
            proj = (inner_product(V[i], U[j]) / inner_product(U[j], U[j])) * U[j]
            u = u - proj
        # normalize
        U.append(u / np.linalg.norm(u))
    return np.array(U)

V = np.array([[1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2]])

U = gram_schmidt(V)
print(U)

Comment: @David This is what I have tried, but it doesn't give the correct result

Comment: don't post code in a comment.

Comment: @MohammedItani as mentioned, don't post code like this in the comments. Your question is lacking detail: add the code to the question. Also, simply saying "it doesn't give the correct result" isn't helpful: what result did it give and what result did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

See [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) for the exact algorithm.

**Note that the norm that you are taking for scaling is the Euclidean norm**, so obviously that would become a problem.
Also if you "normalize" it at each step, you would not need to normalize it in the subtraction process.

Anyways, here is how I did it:

```
import numpy as np

def inner_product(x, y):
    return x[0]*y[0] + 2*x[1]*y[1] + x[2]*y[2]

# Gram Schmidt:
# Take in a list of vectors
def gram_schmidt(V):
    # Orthogonalized, To Be Returned
    orthogonal = []

    # At each step, take vector
    for i in range(len(V)):
        v = copy.deepcopy(V[i])
        
        # Subtract off the "components" from current orthogonal set.
        for j in range(i):
            v = v - inner_product(orthogonal[j], v) * orthogonal[j]
        
        # Normalization
        v = v / ((inner_product(v, v))**0.5)
        orthogonal.append(v)
    
    return orthogonal

# Try the following:
V = [np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([3,2,1]), np.array([4,1,2])]
GS = gram_schmidt(V)
# Should print roughly 0 and 1 respectively
print(inner_product(GS[0], GS[1]))
print(inner_product(GS[0], GS[0]))
```