# is vector component of a along u equal to vector component of u orthogonal to a?

Tags: linear-algebra

is vector component of a along u equal to vector component of u orthogonal to a?

My idea is that in two dimensions, the vector is divided into w1 w2, so it should be composed of two options of w1 or w2, so the following will think that the reverse order is also possible.

but maybe my idea is not rigorous enough, I just think that the reverse projection of the order of u a will have the same result.

I hope someone can solve my problem. I am a student from Taiwan. I may use English grammar incorrectly. Please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Answer**
Assuming u is a unit vector, yes.
(There is a rigorous proof as to, given u, you can extend it to an orthonormal basis for vector space containing the span of u. With this basis {u, u2, u3, ..., un}, you can write a = a1 u + a2 u2 + ... + an un, and take the dot product to get a1.)

**Full Answer**
Still yes, but rigorously speaking, one needs to be careful as to what inner product you are using for your *norm* and *orthogonal*. Generally I am assuming you would use dot product, but there are other inner products that are valid as well.

For example, in an inner product defined as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76381803/gram-schmidt-algorithm-using-nympy-sympy-for-a-custom-inner-product-space/76385749#76385749), the definition of orthogonal would be different from being perpendicular.
This would mean that, expansion of a in the orthonormal (norm is defined in terms of the inner product too!) basis with respect to this inner product: u = a1 u + a2 u2 + ... + an un, you can get a1 by taking the custom inner product, rather than the dot product.